# Mat error is not getting displayed when using with ngModel

Tags: html, angular-reactive-forms, angular9, ngmodel, angular-template-form

I am using mat error in the below way

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  
    <input matInput
            [ngModel]="_control.control.value"
            (ngModelChange)="changeMethod($event)"
            [placeholder]="placeholder"
        >
  <mat-hint>{{hint}}</mat-hint>
  <mat-error>{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

the mat error is not getting displayed even when there is text in errorMessage,_control.control is getting referred to formControl
I had printed even formControl.errors

```
{{_control.control.errors}}
```

I am getting the error object and in the changeMethod i am making the form as touched

```
this._control.control.markAsTouched();
```

What could be the reason for the error not getting displayed
Even the formcontrol value is getting displayed

Comment: Can you share the code of typescript file to get more clear idea.

Comment: In my ts file i am displaying jst the value which is returned.Nothing else is there in ts file